# timezone conversion and date is not displaying properly

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

```
Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(cal.getTimeZone().getID());
cal.set(2012, 8, 21);
java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
System.out.println(d.toString());

//System.setProperty("user.timezone", "America/Chicago");

//  System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Algiers");
//tz1.setDefault(tz1);

cal.setTimeZone(tz1);
System.out.println(cal.getTimeZone().getID());

//cal.set(2012, 8, 21);
System.out.println(d.toString());
```

Output is --

```
Asia/Calcutta
Tue Aug 21 11:35:06 IST 2012
Africa/Algiers
Tue Aug 21 11:35:06 IST 2012
```

I want the time in the currrent timezone format but it is giving in IST. How to do this.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I've only just noticed that the code you're given doesn't even call `cal.getTime()`. You're *completely ignoring* the value in the calendar. It wouldn't do what you wanted anyway, but the value you're printing is just `new Date()`... how do you expect the calendar to get involved?

> I want the time in the currrent timezone format but it is giving in IST. How to do this.

Avoid using `Date.toString`, to start with. A `Date` value has no concept of a time zone, so `toString`just uses the system time zone, always. Changing the time zone of a calendar without calling `set` again doesn't change the underlying value, either.

Now there are two options:

- Use `SimpleDateFormat`, specifying the time zone there before formatting
- Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead, which is a much richer date and time API in the first place

Personally I'd strongly advise you to use the latter option, particularly if you're doing quite a bit of date/time manipulation. `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` just don't let you write code which clearly expresses what data you have at any point in time.

Comment: Hey, I am using Joda time in the project. But still I am facing the problems of conversion. So how to display??

Comment: @Kumar: "how to display" is a *very* broad question. You should start a new question telling us exactly what you want to do, without using `Date` and `Calendar` if you're using Joda Time elsewhere.

Comment: @johnskeet-- I am using jodatime api here and below is the code

Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
  System.out.println(cal.getTimeZone().getID());
  //cal.set(2012, 8, 21,06,05,01);
 
  DateTime d = DateTime.now();
  
  System.out.println(d.toString());
  
  //System.setProperty("user.timezone", "America/Chicago");
  
  // System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
  
  
  TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");//Africa/Algiers
  //Calendar call = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(tz1, Locale.)
  tz1.setDefault(tz1);

Comment: continue -

    cal.setTimeZone(tz1);
  System.out.println(cal.getTimeZone().getID());
  
  //cal.set(2012, 8, 21);
  System.out.println(d.toString());
O/p is -Asia/Calcutta
2012-08-21T12:01:25.564+05:30
America/New_York
2012-08-21T12:01:25.564+05:30

Comment: this is showing some thing wrong. I am using evry where dateTime of joda time API. so this is showing wrong.

Plese check the o/p .

Comment: @Kumar: When I said "start a new question" I meant it. How easy do you find it to read the comments you posted, as code? Do you think it's any easier for me and other users? Note that the code you've posted *still* isn't showing much Joda Time code - it's mostly TimeZone and Calendar.

Comment: I posted as a new question. Sorry for your inconvenience.

Comment: @Kumar: I'm not seeing another question in your profile... care to add a link to it?

Comment: I solved the problems sir. Actually I was doing some mistake and later found it that why then I deleted the question. Very very thanks and regards to you. I think next time if i will have question on Timezone I will consult you. Could you please pass me your email id to be in touch with you. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kumar: No, I'm not your private consultant. Next time you have a question, post it on Stack Overflow again (but more clearly, having read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: My means is not to say that you are my private consultant or any  thing else. Just for being in contact; i askd. Sorry for your inconvenience. I will be posting my queries on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `TimeZone.setDefault(tz1);` instead of `//tz1.setDefault(tz1);`

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(cal.getTimeZone().getID());
    cal.set(2012, 8, 21);
    java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
    System.out.println(d.toString());       

    TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Algiers");
    TimeZone.setDefault(tz1);

    cal.setTimeZone(tz1);
    System.out.println(cal.getTimeZone().getID());

    System.out.println(d.toString());
```

I run your program, see output :

```
Asia/Calcutta
Tue Aug 21 11:47:13 IST 2012
Africa/Algiers
Tue Aug 21 07:17:13 CET 2012
```

Comment: did you notice the difference?

Comment: @JonSkeet is telling you the standard way, use it. I provided just a solution, i.e. to make your program run.

Comment: Please see my comment on "johnskeet". I am basically using JOdaTime API  but when i used it; o/p is using incorrect as per your program too.

Answer (score 0):

Calender doesnot work that way...i have SimpleDateFormat code..it may help..try this

```
public class TimeZoneTest {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        new TimeZoneTest().setTimeZones();  
    }  

    private void setTimeZones(){  

        String etStart = "";  
        String ctStart = "";  
        String mtStart = "";  
        String ptStart = "";  

        DateFormat fullDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");  

                    String dateString = "Mon Mar 14 09:30:51 GMT 2011";  

                                //this input date doesn't convert  
                                //String dateString = "Mon Mar 14 09:30:51 PDT 2011";  

        System.out.println("Input Date: " + dateString);  
        System.out.println("Default TimeZone: " + TimeZone.getDefault());         

        try {  
            etStart = getDateInTimeZone(dateString, fullDateFormat, TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));  
            ctStart = getDateInTimeZone(dateString, fullDateFormat, TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));  
            mtStart = getDateInTimeZone(dateString, fullDateFormat, TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Denver"));  
            ptStart = getDateInTimeZone(dateString, fullDateFormat, TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));  
        } catch (ParseException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
                                 }  

        System.out.println("Eastern Date: " + etStart);  
        System.out.println("Central Date: " + ctStart);  
        System.out.println("Mountain Date: " + mtStart);  
        System.out.println("Pacific Date: " + ptStart);       

    }  

     private String getDateInTimeZone(Date inputDt, TimeZone targetTimeZone) throws ParseException{  

        DateFormat fullDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");  
        fullDateFormat.setTimeZone(targetTimeZone);  
        return fullDateFormat.format(inputDt);  

    }  

}
```